# ElasticSearch heap size, half of all ram or half of available?

Tags: elasticsearch

This may be a silly question, but I really confused. According to this document [Give less than half your memory to lucene](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html#_give_less_than_half_your_memory_to_lucene), it is recommend to give 50% of memory to ES, and lucene will take the rest. My question is I have a 8GB machine with some daemons running, that leaves 4GB available. should I set es heap size to half of 8 or half of 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 8GB of physical memory available and 4GB are already taken by some processes, that means no other process will be able to use that space.

This means that you effectively have 4GB of memory left that you can share between ES (for the heap) and Lucene (for the file cache), i.e. 2GB to ES and Lucene will take what's left.